# Copy to clipboard from a paragraph or button (no input fields)

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking a a simple solution:

- I just have a text (it can be a button without borders or paragraph or span, but no input field)
- I want to be able to just click on text and to be copied to clipboard (in all common web browsers)
- without any additional buttons
- after clicking display a tooltip.

Just like that:
[image]

I saw many articles but based on input field.
I also tried to use this code: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard2
It looks very nice with tooltip but there is the additional button and it is based on input field.

How to do this, using only one text field (it can be a button without borders or paragraph or span, but no input field) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign both listeners to a normal element, it doesn't need to be a button.
Starting from the w3schools example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span id="myText" onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
    <span>Text to copy</span>
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myText");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.firstElementChild.innerText);
  
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.firstElementChild.innerText;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 100px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[See codepen preview](https://codepen.io/JanRezzonico/pen/eYQyZZL)

Comment: It works exactly as I wanted. Just 1 text and no buttons!!!!
Thank you.

How would the code look like if we place 2 or 3 similar texts next to each other, and everyone can be copied separately?

Comment: In the html call the functions with the keyword “this” as a parameter, and in the javascript instead of using the getElementById function, you use the obtained parameter. For getting the tooltip you could select the last child of the parameter (param.lastElementChild)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Code:

```html
<p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myInput" value="Copied text">Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  // Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  // Alert the copied text
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

Using a button we're calling our function `myFunction` once the button is clicked. In our function we copy the value we gave our button, in this case *"Copied text"* and alert the user, that the text was copied.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why you've struggled to follow this is becuase of the first few lines in the code (which is specific to `input` tags).
But you can adapt the remaining code like so:
(Adapted from the [W3 Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard2)

I believe the bit that causes you some issue is

```js
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
```

Which I believe is to help some mobile browsers to grab the `value` from the input, but since you want a different element type (in my example: `<p>...</p>`), I don't believe it is needed...

In the below snippet:

- I targeted `#myTarget`
- Copied the `innerText`

  - You could always use different properties if needed, such as `innerHTML`
  - [MDN Documentaion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)
- Outputted the content of the text to show to the user

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myTarget");

  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.innerText);

  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.innerText;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

  <p id="myTarget">The world says hello</p>

  <div class="tooltip">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```